# How to get a hash of the source code in Rust

Tags: build, rust

For checking compatibility between a client and a server, I'd like to compare the versions of their shared code. I have implemented this by a `build.rs` that creates a hash of the content of all files under `src/`, but it seems brittle. I want to make sure I calculate a hash of the files that are actually used in the build. Surely this is already done at some point during the build process.

There is a feature to [Add hash of source files in debug info](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/69718), which sounds promising, but it adds the data to the debug information, and I want to get it at runtime.

Comment: Note that computing the hash of the source is not enough, at least in the general case: Proc-macros can expand into anything they want, which may not be stable, even if the invocation-site (which is hashed) doesn't change. As the answer below suggests, I'd go with semantic versioning, which is used everywhere not because it's its the best solution but because it's the least bad one. There is also [built](https://crates.io/crates/built), which gives you the git commit id of your build and an indication if the working directory had been clean.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for compatibility, then I'm afraid just checking *your* source code is not enough (at least, this isn't always true). You might rely on some crate for some feature and if you change the version of it, it might still fail.

So if you want to go the hashing route, then you'll need to hash the entire project including the Cargo.lock file. And yes, you would indeed do it through the build.rs script.

However, I would not go that route.

Version numbers are usually used for this. In Rust, you're supposed to use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). With this system you can see from the numbers whether two crate versions are compatible.

Comment: In this case, I don't think updating a dependency would break it, so checking *my* code should be enough. It's not supposed to be a super-secure check; rather a way to avoid mistakes during development. Bumping a version number for every potentially breaking change during development sounds like too much of a hassle for this purpose.

Comment: IMO, in practice, it's not that bad to do. Of course it depends on how often you release.
If you have a good setup in git and do pull requests, it's a good thing to do regardless.
So my tip is that you try the 'normal' way. If then you don't like it, you can always go to trying to hash the project.